# keep focus on another application during sendkey using c#

Tags: c#, focus, sendkeys

I've searched for the last two days how to keep focus on another application during SendKeys.SendWait() in C#. What I really wanna do is to use Thread.Sleep(3000) to let some time to the user to click in the targeted app (which I don't have access to the code) and Send keys from my c# app.

The problem is, during the send keys, if the user clicks in the notepad or any other window, it just drops all the keys in that window instead of continuing in the app I targeted at first.

I have found that using sendkeys in old VB was working like I wanted but I really need to use it in c#.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You should read through the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the site. Try to include any code you have attempted and indicate where you are having your problem, along with a description of what you are trying to do compared to what is actually happening.

Comment: you might be able to send keys to your `out of focus` app by using its hWnd handle. need to get the handle first and then might need to use a PInvoke in C# to send the keys to it. It might come back to focus though. but with experimentation you'll see more.